# CACHE-MANIFEST for Websphere 7

Tags: caching, websphere, manifest, websphere-7

Trying to set up an appcache file as described in [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#manifests). It requires the file to be served with MIME type of text/cache-manifest. So I open the WAS console and navigate to environment > virtual hosts > default_host > mime types and add the new property. However, the new property never shows up in the console view. I have confirmed the xml on the file system contains the entry. But after restarting the server and checking, still nothing. The file continues to be served as text/plain. Ideas?

Is this unsupported in version 7x of Websphere?

Comment: Are you saving those changes when prompted, subsequent to hitting OK? If this is ND, are you synchronizing the node the server is on?

Comment: Yes. Saving as normal. No log messages to indicate otherwise.